# I'm having issues setting up my jest config react native Cannot Import Components

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm having issues related somehow maybe to babel configs or package.json file... in short i can't import any component from outside the test file

here's the error:

```
 E:\.......\src\components\ButtonInstance.jsx:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import React from 'react';
      2 | import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';
    > 3 | import ButtonInstance from '../src/components/ButtonInstance';
        | ^

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/index.test.js:3:1)
```

here's my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import ButtonInstance from '../example/src/ButtonInstance';

test('Button', () => {
  const onPressMock = jest.fn();
  const { getByText } = render(<ButtonInstance onPress={onPressMock} />);
  fireEvent.press(getByText('Press me'));
  expect(onPressMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

and here is my button instance Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default function ButtonInstance(onPress) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}>
      <Text>Press me</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "components-example",
  "description": "Example app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@iconscout/react-native-unicons": "^1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.5.3",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0"
  }
}
```

and last file babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-flow',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: '10',
        },
        bugfixes: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
};
```

folders structure

```
|__ __tests__
         |__ index.test.js

|__ node_modules

|__ src
    |__ components
             |__ ButtonInstance.jsx

|__ babel.config.js

|__ package.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue it was related somehow to babel configs you can add these files to your app here is the new babel working config file (maybe it helps someone):

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache(true);

  return {
    env: {
      development: {
        plugins: [
          [
            'module-resolver',
            {
              root: ['./src'],
              extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
            },
          ],
        ],
      },
    },
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }]],
  };
};
```

And the jest config file:

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'svg'],
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(js|ts)x?$',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js',
    '^.+\\.svg$': 'jest-svg-transformer',
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['\\.snap$', '<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  cacheDirectory: '.jest/cache',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(react-native|react-navigation|react-navigation-tabs|react-navigation-redux-helpers|react-native-safari-view|react-native-linear-gradient|react-native-blur|react-native-animatable|react-native-wkwebview-reborn|react-native-safe-area-view|react-native-popup-menu|redux-persist)/)',
  ],
};
```